# PostgreSQL - conditional ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
key | date         | flag
--------------------------
1    now()           true
2    now() - 1 hour  true
3    now() + 1 hour  true
4    now()           false
5    now() - 1 hour  false
6    now() + 1 hour  false
```

I want the following sorting:

- First, all rows with `flag = false`. These rows must be sorted with `date asc`.
- Then, all other rows (`flag = true`). However, these rows must be sorted with `date desc`.

Is the following query correct?

```
(
    select *
    from test
    where flag = false
    order by date asc
)
union all
(
    select *
    from test
    where flag = true
    order by date desc
)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Will the `union all` keep the rows sorted, and therefore just concatenate the output of the two inner queries?

I don't know how to repeat the columns in the `order by`, based on a condition.

**update**

Fiddle can be found here: http://rextester.com/FFOSS79584

Comment: conditional ordering is done with `CASE`

Comment: smth like `order by flag,case when flag then date end desc, case when not flag then date end asc` http://rextester.com/FDAY76293

Answer (score 51, accepted):

conditional order can be performed with `CASE`, like here:

```
select *
    from test
order by 
    flag
  , case when flag then date end desc
  , case when not flag then date end asc
```

Comment: But won't this always order by ```flag```? In my case, I'd like to either make all cases optional or have a default sort field. The cases should be exclusive