# PostgreSQL conditional multiple order by with asc/desc

Tags: postgresql

I want to order by multiple columns conditionally, but not only by a single order type for all the columns (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322046/postgresql-conditional-ordering)).

I want to accomplish something like this (not valid sql as I don't know how to do it, just trying to convey the idea):

```
-- assume this is wrapped by a function with a `_sort` string argument
select * from t_test 
order by
case when _sort='sort_type_1' then (
    col1 desc, col2 asc, col3 desc, col4 asc)
case when _sort='sort_type_2' then (
    col1 asc, col2 asc, col3 desc, col4 asc)
case when _sort='sort_type_3' then (
    col1 desc, col2 desc, col3 asc, col4 asc)
else (
    col4 desc, col3 asc)
end;
```

Note that the order of `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` matter, so I couldn't do something like this:

```
select * from t_test
order by
col2, col4
case when _sort='sort_type_1' then (col1, col3) end desc;
```

Is this possible with a similar approach, or is an entirely different one necessary?

Comment: Is `_sort` a column of `t_test`? Or is it a variable you're setting?

Comment: `_sort` is a string argument (the `select` is wrapped by a postgres function) - see the comment in code. so no, `_sort` is not a column of `t_test`.

Comment: Your  CASE has no ELSE, so what is the default supposed to be?

Comment: I was trying to show only what I thought was necessary, but maybe more will be helpful

Comment: You probably want to approach this by having 4 different versions of the query in your function and having 4 different "RETURN QUERY" statements, choosing which to execute by a plpgsql-level (not SQL level) CASE.  Or you could compose the query string from pieces, and execute it as dynamic SQL.