# PLPGSQL Function: Use Input Parameter in ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to define a conditional ORDER BY in a plpgsql function.
Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(p_sort_order TEXT, p_limit INTEGER) 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        id TEXT,
        test TEXT
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 
                    t.field1 AS id,
                    MIN(t.field2) AS test 
                    FROM table t
                    GROUP BY t.field1
            ORDER BY 
            CASE p_sort_order
                WHEN ‘asc’ THEN test END ASC,
                WHEN ‘desc’ THEN test END DESC
            END
            LIMIT p_limit;
END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

It seems like the parameters only work in the WHERE, LIMIT, etc. clause but not with ORDER BY (even though I haven't found any official documentation on this).

What is a workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: Interesting question.  This looks promising: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322272/13808319

Comment: @MikeOrganek Yes. This is what I am trying to do. But it doesn't seem to work if the "flag" is an input parameter in a plpgsql function. I don't get an error. It just doesn't sort it. I have seen comments in forums, that input parameters cannot be used with ORDER BY for reasons unknown. I was wondering if anyone knows a workaround.

Comment: In this specific case you could use `ORDER BY test * CASE p_sort_order WHEN 'asc' THEN 1 WHEN 'desc' THEN -1 END` (though you might have to handle `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST`).

Comment: @Marth Interesting. I have never seen that. But I get following error for the asterisk: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text * integer

Comment: @Palmi: nevermind, I missed that `test` is an `text`. My 'solution' can't work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the link, change your `select` thusly:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN min(t.field2) END ASC,
   CASE WHEN p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN min(t.field2) END DESC
LIMIT p_limit;
```

The magic here is that both `case` instances return either `test` or `null` with either `asc` or `desc` following.  If the `p_sort_order` is `desc`, then you get:

```
  ORDER BY 
    NULL ASC,
    test DESC
```

The `NULL ASC` makes all rows equal in collation, so the `order by` falls through to the `test DESC` term.

This works for me on PG10 (updated per your comment):

```
create or replace function do_sort(p_sort_order text)
  returns table (id int, name text)
as $$
  begin
    return query select users.id, min(users.email)
                   from users
                  group by users.id
                  order by case when p_sort_order = 'asc' then min(users.email) end asc,
                           case when p_sort_order = 'desc' then min(users.email) end desc
                  limit 10;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 10.849 ms

select * from do_sort('desc');

┌───────┬───────────────────────┐
│  id   │         name          │
├───────┼───────────────────────┤
│     9 │ 9user@example.com     │
│    99 │ 99user@example.com    │
│   999 │ 999user@example.com   │
│  9999 │ 9999user@example.com  │
│ 99999 │ 99999user@example.com │
│ 99998 │ 99998user@example.com │
│ 99997 │ 99997user@example.com │
│ 99996 │ 99996user@example.com │
│ 99995 │ 99995user@example.com │
│ 99994 │ 99994user@example.com │
└───────┴───────────────────────┘
(10 rows)

Time: 87.236 ms

select * from do_sort('asc');

┌────────┬────────────────────────┐
│   id   │          name          │
├────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ 100000 │ 100000user@example.com │
│ 100001 │ 100001user@example.com │
│ 100002 │ 100002user@example.com │
│ 100003 │ 100003user@example.com │
│ 100004 │ 100004user@example.com │
│  10000 │ 10000user@example.com  │
│  10001 │ 10001user@example.com  │
│  10002 │ 10002user@example.com  │
│  10003 │ 10003user@example.com  │
│  10004 │ 10004user@example.com  │
└────────┴────────────────────────┘
(10 rows)

Time: 85.219 ms
```

Comment: I tried that too. But again, it doesn't work if p_sort_order is a input parameter in a plpgsql function. There is no effect. Have you tried this?

Comment: I don't get any error. It just doesn't sort it. Maybe the GROUP BY was the problem all along. Could you please adjust your function to following select and try again: select users.id as id, min(users.name) as name from users group by users.id order by case when p_sort_order = 'asc' then name end asc, case when p_sort_order = 'desc' then name end desc limit 10;

Comment: @Palmi  I added a script to my answer and changed the `CASE` statement to avoid an ambiguous column error.

Comment: @Palmi  Mine choked on using `name` in the `order by`.  I changed it to `min(user.email)` to get around it, and it worked.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think my problem was that I used the alias from the select statement

Comment: @Palmi  To be fair, the alias was what I put in my original answer.  Sorry about that!